Roof sagging,dips
Last week a roofing company replaced my roof and garage. They told me they were gonna resheet everything, but they didn't. They said some of it wasn't bad. Does this look good to you? They only replaced a few sheets, and on my back porch the sheet they put on the isn't nailed to rafter at all.

Do you have a written contract of what they said they will do?  If so, this sounds more like a question to ask a lawyer.  Quite often roof sheets do not need replacing, but depends on the condition.  With a contract, you can have another roofer check the work and then a lawyer if first roofer does not make right.

Is there supposed to be a picture attached to your post?

You forgot to attach a picture.  It would be odd to quote a customer to replace ALL sheets, rather than "all necessary" ones.  It would just make the quote look high.  If they did not leave behind any rotten or damaged sheets I would expect your contract to be on their side.  Pictures of the not-nailed sheet would help produce answers.  How can you tell?  Can you easily lift the whole sheet off from underneath?
